# Ability to like a Facebook post thru the Like Button Social plugin

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

Is there a way to give a Facebook Post URL to the [Like Button Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and have users like it thru the Plugin - such that it affects the Like Count for the Post on the Wall ?

I have tried to give a Facebook Fan Page (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/cocacola) to the Like Button Plugin and it seems to work - that is - by clicking on the plugin like button results in actually liking the Facebook page. See working jsfiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/wAeYE/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cocacola" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am interested in doing this with a Facebook post. I have already tried to give http://www.facebook.com/source_id/posts/post_id (where source_id is the PageId - [example here](http://www.facebook.com/PhotoContestApp/posts/312241432219459)). This URL  takes me to the actual Facebook post. The Like plugin works and does allow me to 'like' it, however it does not translate into liking the post on the Wall.

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: I too would like to know this. It doesn't seem like facebook gives a way to discriminate